# React hook : How to call through multiple button inside a Class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So i am using a React hook

```
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
export const useAuthenticatedCallback = (callbackFn) => {
    const [keycloak, initialized] = useKeycloak()
  
    const authCallback = useCallback(() => {
      
      // if user is not authenticated redirect to login
      if (!keycloak.authenticated) {
        return keycloak.login()
      }
  
      // otherwise invoke function
      return callbackFn()
    }, [callbackFn, initialized, keycloak])
  
    return authCallback
  }
```

and used in react class like a component

```
function AuthenticatedCallback(props) {
    const authenticatedCallback = useAuthenticatedCallback(props);
    return props.children(authenticatedCallback);
  }
class Posts extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
handleTradeCallSubmit(){
       
        if(this.state.tradeCallFormValid){
            // To DO
            this.setState({ ...this.state, tradeCallFormValid: false});
            let _postForm = this.state.postForm;
            let _companyCode = this.state.companyCode;

            let requestBody = {
                eventType:'create-trade-call-post', 
                callType:_postForm.tradeTypeId,
                symbol:_companyCode,
                userId: this.props.activeUser.Id,
                price:_postForm.price,
                stopLoss:_postForm.stopLoss,
                targetPrice:_postForm.targetPrice,
                targetDate:_postForm.targetDate,
                tags: _companyCode,
                title:_postForm.title,
                notes:_postForm.notes
            }
        
            postService.create(requestBody)
                .then((result) => {
                    NotificationManager.success(`Trade call post created successfully...`);
                    this.loadPosts(1);
                    this.clearTradeCallForm();
                }).catch((error) => {
                    NotificationManager.error(`Trade call post creation failed..`);
                    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
                });
        } else {
            let _postForm = this.state.postForm;
            _postForm.isValidationActive = true;
            this.setState({ ...this.state, postForm: _postForm});
        }
        
    }
.............................
.............................
  render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <CircularSpinner />;
        }

        return ( <AuthenticatedCallback handleTradeCallSubmit={this.handleTradeCallSubmit}>{authenticatedCallback => 
        <div>
            <NotificationContainer/>
            <Card>
                <CardContent>
                    <form ref={(ref) => this.formRef = ref} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                        <Grid className="text-center" container spacing={2}>
                        {
                            this.state.postTypes.map((postType, index) => 
                                <Grid key={postType.Id} item sm={6} xs={6} md={3}>
                                    <h5>{postType.Name} <Switch  key={postType.Id}  checked={(postType.Name === 'TradeCall')?this.state.isTradeCallActive: !this.state.isTradeCallActive} value={postType.Id} onChange={this.handleChange} name={postType.Name} inputProps={(postType.Name === 'TradeCall') ? {'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }: { 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox' }} /></h5>
                                </Grid>
                            )                            
                        }
                            
                        <div className={!this.state.isTradeCallActive ? 'hidden' : ''}>
                            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                <Grid item sm={12} xs={12} md={2}>
                                    <ButtonGroup fullWidth aria-label="small button group">
                                        <Button onClick={()=>{this.setState({ ...this.state, tradeTypeSelected: "Sale"})}}
                                            variant={(this.state.tradeTypeSelected === "Buy") ? "outlined" : "contained"} 
                                            color={(this.state.tradeTypeSelected === "Buy") ? "default" : "secondary"}> Sale
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button onClick={()=>{this.setState({ ...this.state, tradeTypeSelected: "Buy"})}} 
                                            variant={(this.state.tradeTypeSelected === "Buy") ? "contained" : "outlined"} 
                                            color={(this.state.tradeTypeSelected === "Buy") ? "secondary" : "default"}> Buy
                                        </Button>
                                    </ButtonGroup>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item sm={12} xs={12} md={2}>
                                    <TextField fullWidth id="txtPrice" error={this.state.postForm.isValidationActive && !this.state.postForm.priceValid} name="txtPrice" type="number" InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0} }} size="small" label="Price" onChange={this.handleChange} variant="outlined" placeholder="Price.."  />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item sm={12} xs={12} md={2}>
                                    <TextField fullWidth id="txtStoploss" error={this.state.postForm.isValidationActive && !this.state.postForm.stopLossValid} name="txtStoploss" type="number" InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0} }}  size="small" label="Stoploss" onChange={this.handleChange} variant="outlined" placeholder="SL.."  />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item sm={12} xs={12} md={2}>
                                    <TextField fullWidth id="txtTarget" error={this.state.postForm.isValidationActive && !this.state.postForm.targetPriceValid} name="txtTarget" type="number" InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0} }}  size="small" label="Target price" onChange={this.handleChange} variant="outlined" placeholder="Price.."  />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item sm={12} xs={12} md={4}>
                                    <TextField fullWidth id="targetDate" error={this.state.postForm.isValidationActive && !this.state.postForm.targetDateValid} name="targetDate" onChange={this.handleChange} type="date" size="small" label="Target date" variant="outlined"  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, }} />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                                                       
                                 
                            <Grid justify="center"  container spacing={2}>
                                <Grid item sm={12} xs={12} md={3}>
                                    <Button size="medium" fullWidth id="btnSubmit" startIcon={<SaveIcon />} onClick={authenticatedCallback} variant="contained" color="primary"> Save </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                     
      }
      </AuthenticatedCallback>)
    }
  } 

// Map redux state to props
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    activeUser: state.session.activeUser
  });
  
// export the component.
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Posts);
```

Now in button i am calling it like this

```
<Button size="medium" fullWidth id="btnSubmit" startIcon={<SaveIcon />} onClick={authenticatedCallback} variant="contained" color="primary"> Save </Button>
```

But i have a multiple button here inside this react class what will approach to call same React hook to check user login or not?

Comment: You cannot use hooks in class components.

Comment: @HMR thanks you are right but i created a component that uses the hook, and then used the component inside the class  .

Answer (score 0):

So here is one Solution I got with one of my friend
suggest in Hook Component function

```
function AuthenticatedCallback(props) {
    const authenticatedCallback = useAuthenticatedCallback(props.handleTradeCallSubmit);
    const authenticatedCallback1 = useAuthenticatedCallback(props.handleAnalysisSubmit);
    return  props.children(authenticatedCallback,authenticatedCallback1);
  }
```

and changes in class level

```
<AuthenticatedCallback handleTradeCallSubmit={this.handleTradeCallSubmit} handleAnalysisSubmit={this.handleAnalysisSubmit}>{(authenticatedCallback,authenticatedCallback1) => 
        <div>
            <NotificationContainer/>
.............................
.............................
  <Button size="medium" fullWidth id="btnSubmit" startIcon={<SaveIcon />} onClick={authenticatedCallback}  variant="contained" color="primary"> Save </Button>
 <Button fullWidth size="medium" id="btnAnalysisSubmit" startIcon={<SaveIcon />} onClick={authenticatedCallback1}  variant="contained" color="primary"> Save </Button>
    </div>
      }
      </AuthenticatedCallback>)
   }
  }
```